# q-stepper header-nav aligns itself to right when only one q-step is appear

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

q-stepper header-nav aligns itself towards the right when only one q-step appears.
But when there are two steps or more everything looks normal.
when I disable the following CSS in chrome dev tool it aligns itself to left.

```
.q-stepper__header--standard-labels .q-stepper__tab:last-child {
justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

and the following css got disabled by itself for some reason

```
q-stepper__header--standard-labels .q-stepper__tab:first-child {
justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

it looks like q-stepper recognize it as the last child when there is only one q-step appears.

codepen: https://codepen.io/samnnywong/pen/jOBEmQb

I am not sure if this is expected behaviour, but if it is, is there a proper way to make it aligns to left?

Comment: I'd report an issue and see what the authors have to say